# syntastic plugin files getting sourced twice

Tags: plugin-syntastic

Many moons ago, I made the common newb mistake of tricking out vim with all kinds of plugins and plugin loaders without really knowing what I was doing. I'm trying to clean things up a little. I'm still a little baffled, though.

I just discovered the `vim --startuptime` switch. I was looking at its output and noticed syntastic files were getting sourced twice, causing a big drag on load time:

```
087.736  000.744  000.609: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/ale/plugin/ale.vim
088.335  000.019  000.019: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim
088.410  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim
088.478  000.018  000.018: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim
088.542  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim
088.606  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim
088.670  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim
088.741  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim
088.803  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim
088.869  000.016  000.016: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim
088.933  000.014  000.014: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim
089.637  000.480  000.480: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/util.vim
617.294  000.056  000.056: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim
617.409  000.051  000.051: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim
617.700  000.200  000.200: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim
617.855  000.100  000.100: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim
617.993  000.085  000.085: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim
618.331  000.286  000.286: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim
618.478  000.092  000.092: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim
618.607  000.077  000.077: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim
619.003  000.344  000.344: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim
619.161  000.093  000.093: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim
620.128  531.146  529.281: sourcing /Users/me/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
```

I'm trying to track down what causing this behavior. I commented out everything in my `.vimrc` file having to do with syntastic. I notice in the output above, a file called `util.vim` in the `autoload` directory gets called. I'm wondering if that might be the culprit. But I'm just not sure.

The syntastic plugin is located in `~/.vim/bundle`. I have pathogen in the `.vimrc` like so:

```
"====[ Pathogen support ]======================
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

Comment: Looks like this is just how syntastic works: https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/1580 But I'm getting over 1/2 second additional load time, which seems insane.

Comment: OK, it's something in my .vimrc file that's dragging things down. With a blank .vimrc and only a pathogen#infect() in there, it syntastic loads really fast.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51 might be helpful.